# Emacs 22.3 does not compile on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: emacs, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded emacs 22.3 from

http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/emacs-22.3.tar.gz

onto my Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS desktop and compile/make doesn't work.

Configure seems to work fine.

Make fails very early on: in subdirectory lib-src there's a problem on line 148 of the makefile. And it does look like a problem:

```
ALL_CFLAGS = -D_BSD_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
          -I. -I../src -I${srcdir} -I${srcdir}/../src ${LDFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}
```

That's lines 147 and 148: line 148 is supposed to be a continuation of line 147 I guess. It begins with a tab. No \ at the end of line 147. I put one in and tried again. I got an error on line 150. I put in another \ . A few lines later things got a bit more serious, where absence of \ actually resulted in things that weren't syntax errors but made make break in more subtle ways.

I shouldn't be editing Makefiles anyway (I can tell, their permissions were read-only ;-) ). What am I doing wrong? I could persevere, but if I could instead e.g. feed a flag to make to e.g. run in emacs-22.3-makefile-compatibility mode, that would be much better.

[for those wondering "why" -- I have some scripts which I need for my work, and they have never worked in emacs >=23; on my old machine I just compiled emacs22 myself no problem, but on this new Ubuntu machine I have no emacs22 and there's no emacs22 in ubuntu 12.04 repository so I'm a little desperate]

---

OK so it was suggested that I tried

```
$ CPPFLAGS="-P" ./configure
```

and this sorts out all of the problems with the carriage return/tabs in lib-src. But actually it just gets to me to the point where I had managed to get manually:

```
cd src; make all  \
          CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-g -O2 -Wno-pointer-sign ' CPPFLAGS='-D_BSD_SOURCE  -P' \
          LDFLAGS='-Wl,-znocombreloc' MAKE='make'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/buzzard/local/emacs-22.3/src'
gcc -c -D_BSD_SOURCE  -P -Demacs -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I. -I/home/buzzard/local/emacs-22.3/src -D_BSD_SOURCE  -g -O2 -Wno-pointer-sign  pre-crt0.c
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/crt1.o', needed by `temacs'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/buzzard/local/emacs-22.3/src'
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

Umm...I would post other bits and bobs if I knew what I was doing, but to be honest I've never understood make. I've always just hoped it would work...

Comment: do you need the "cd src".  i've usually just run make from the top-level emacs dir (same dir where i ran configure).  usually it's just "configure" followed by "make".

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might try running the `autogen.sh` script to rebuild the configure script, in case there are some incompatibilities which can be sorted out automatically.

Comment: Ah, 22.3 doesn't have autogen.sh. You could possibly take a look at the script from a more recent version to see what it does and replicate it manually, but that might turn out to be a bunch of effort for no actual benefit, and I guess the `INSTALL` file would be a better bet in any case.

Comment: You could also try posting a question about the problems with running the elisp scripts in Emacs 24, as it might be reasonably easy to update them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem with newer gcc versions. See this change in the Emacs repo which fixed this:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=commit;h=16abbbf

You should be able to workaraound the problem by using

```
CPPFLAGS="-P" ./configure
```

To circumvent the problem with /usr/lib/crt1.o not being found, you'll have to edit `src/Makefile` (you might first have to do `chmod a+rw src/Makefile` for editing it). On newer systems, crt1.o is not in `/usr/lib` but in `/usr/lib/<arch directory>/`, so for example it might be in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` (yours might be different!). Then in `src/Makefile`, change the lines

```
STARTFILES = pre-crt0.o /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/crti.o
```

to

```
STARTFILES = pre-crt0.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crti.o
```

and

```
LIBES = ... all kinds of stuff ...  /usr/lib/crtn.o $(GNULIB_VAR)
```

to

```
LIBES = ... all kinds of stuff ... /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o $(GNULIB_VAR)
```

Again, your directory might be different!

Comment: Great -- thanks! It now compiles. FWIW, on my ubuntu 12.04 desktop, it was /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o [note to anyone else reading: note that there are *three* instances of i386-linux-gnu above that hence need changing to x86_64-linux-gnu]. Emacs then compiles with make as usual. The sting in the tail was that it didn't run :-) It failed with "emacs: Cannot open termcap database file". I fixed this by installing libncurses5-dev and then completely starting again. So if you want to edit your answer to be the complete solution for ubuntu 12.04 you might want to mention this at the start.